# S5 as the adjunction of possibility and necessity

Tags: logic, category-theory, modal-logic

I found this statement in the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S5_(modal_logic)) for the modal system S5: [image]

I looked at the reference but it just states the claim without any further commentary, just like the wikipedia article. Can someone tell me what this means? I.e. what exactly are the categories and functors?

Is it as simple as $\square p \to q$ iff $p\to \Diamond q$ for all propositional formulas p and q?

Comment: It’s that $p\to\square q$ iff $\lozenge p\to q$.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen That’s to say $\vdash (p \to \Box q) \iff \vdash \Diamond p \to q$, not $(p \to \Box q)⊣ \vdash (\Diamond p \to q)$, right?

Comment: @PW_246 my main goal with that comment was to tell op they got left and right backwards. My thought was for some fixed frame “$p\to\square q$ is true everywhere iff $\lozenge p\to q$ is” but that seems to only require the frame to be symmetric.